# Convert single-file .vue components to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

Is there a tool out there that can take a `.vue` template like this:

```
<template>
  <div>Hello, {{ thing }}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() { return { thing: 'World' }; }
  }
</script>

<style>
  div { background: red; }
</style>
```

And convert it into a `.js` file, like this:

```
export default {
  template: `
    <div>Hello {{ thing }}</div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      thing: 'World'
    }
  }
}
```

(Not sure what magic it'd do with the CSS, but it'd do something.)

I'm trying to use native browser modules, which work great, but I'd like to use the `.vue` file syntax since it offers some nice things. I'd like to avoid using a bundler like Webpack or Browserify.

I am using Babel. I have the `transform-vue-jsx` plugin, but that can't handle the `.vue` format, only converting the JSX.

Comment: As written, your question sounds terribly like you didn't search for this yourself yet? Also, based on the final part of your question, it sounds very much like you presented an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), where your real question should be "how do I make babel/webpack/etc bundle in `.vue` files" since that's what you're ultimately trying to resolve. For instance, https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader is trivially found with google if this is babel + webpack.

Comment: @Mike OP said they'd rather avoid using Webpack or Browserify, otherwise for sure Webpack is the way to go.

Comment: Going to counter with "go where the solutions are, first, then see if you're still unhappy", given that people have already made the process of using a bundler pretty much a prefab solution for almost every popular framework by now. Not wanting to use webpack/browserify when you're already using babel is a bit like closing the barn door when the horses have already bolted.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I did do quite a bit of searching, and I came across webpack and browserify solutions. They're hard to miss, they start right on the documentation for the single file component, and come up in just about every google search. However, as I said, I specifically don't want to bundle, which is what both of those tools do. I'm trying to use the new native module functionality for some specific reasons. Not wanting to bundle has nothing to do with using Babel for the latest and greatest JS syntax support.

Comment: a recommendation is to at the very least file an issue on the vue repository asking for this, because if as you say there is no information about this on the internet, then you should ask them to add a "how to do this" to their readme, or documentation, *somewhere*, on their side. That is not information that should be only found in a stackoverflow answer. That's not how open source works (or, should work =)

Comment: That's not a bad idea, and if the solution proposed below works, I likely will. Though, I was looking to see if an answer existed that I missed first. ;)

Comment: @Mike I’d also like to point out that I stumbled on this question for different reasons than the OP asked it, but I was specifically looking for exactly what the OP asked. Sometimes a question may seem like a “you asked for foo but what you really want is bar” but there is still value to the poster and the community at large in answering the original question asked - you never know when someone is going to need exactly that.

Comment: sure, but also not an argument not to - if you had a different problem, but with the same answer, it's an almost guaranteed bet that posting your own question with the exact text that describes your problem, today, would have gotten you an answer that same day, and then people searching for the same problem in the future would find your question, not this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can utilize [vue-template-compiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-template-compiler) to parse the *.vue files and extract the relevant sections.

I've written a node script which should do the job:

**convert.js**

```es6
const compiler = require('vue-template-compiler');

let content = '';

process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.on('data', buf => {
    content += buf.toString();
});

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    const parsed = compiler.parseComponent(content);
    const template = parsed.template ? parsed.template.content : '';
    const script = parsed.script ? parsed.script.content : '';

    const templateEscaped = template.trim().replace(/`/g, '\\`');
    const scriptWithTemplate = script.match(/export default ?\{/)
        ? script.replace(/export default ?\{/, `$&\n\ttemplate: \`\n${templateEscaped}\`,`)
        : `${script}\n export default {\n\ttemplate: \`\n${templateEscaped}\`};`;

    process.stdout.write(scriptWithTemplate);
});
```

To convert all *.vue files to *.vue.js, run the following bash command inside the directory containing the *.vue files (assuming you're using linux or macOS):

```bash
find . -name '*.vue' -exec bash -c 'node convert.js < "{}" > "{}.js"' \;
```

This will result in the following conversion:

**foo.vue**

```vue
<template>
    <div>a</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'foo',
    };
</script>

<style>
    /* Won't be extracted */
</style>
```

**foo.vue.js (generated)**

```es6
export default {
    template: `
        <div>a</div>
    `,
    name: 'foo',
};
```

You might want to tweak the script so that it deals with extracting the styles (however you want that to be handled) and fixing up whitespace and stuff like that.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it might be just what I'm after. Kind of surprised I couldn't find that package as it looks used quite a bit. Must be buried by results for `vue-loader`. I'll give it a try this evening.

Answer (score 3):

I've put together an online vue converter which allows you to copy/paste your vue-file and convert it to said javascript.

https://fluxfx.nl/htools/vue-conv

[image: Online Vue Converter]

Answer (score 1):

This is my edit for Typescript

```
const parser = require("vue-template-compiler");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const glob = require("glob");

function getFiles(src, callback) {
  glob(src + "/**/*.vue", callback);
}

getFiles(path.join(__dirname, "../src"), function(err, filePaths) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    filePaths.forEach(filePath => {
      fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const parsed = parser.parseComponent(data);
        if (!parsed.script) {
          return;
        }
        fs.writeFile(
          filePath.replace("vue", "ts"),
          parsed.script.content,
          err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(`The file ${filePath} has been created!`);
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }
});
```

I am using it for sonarcube static analyses of my typscript codes, since sonarcube does not support vue SFC for now.

There is no cleanup, because I am running it in gitlab pipeline so after pipeline is done, it is all cleaned automatically.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated version that works with Vue 3 single file components:

package.json:

```
{
      "name": "vue3-sfc-convert",
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "convert.js",
      "scripts": {
        "convert": "node convert.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "glob": "^7.2.0",
        "vue": "^3.2.20"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.20"
      }
}
```

convert.js

```
/**
 * convert.js
 * 
 * Convert Vue3 Single File Component to stand-alone script with template property
 * Run node convert.js in directory containing *.vue files
 * Output will be .vue files converted to .ts files with template property set to contents of SFC template block
 */
const sfcCompiler = require("@vue/compiler-sfc");
const fs = require("fs");
const glob = require("glob");

const COMPONENT_START = "export default defineComponent({";

function convertSFC(filePath) {
  try {
    fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        try {
          const parsed = sfcCompiler.parse(data);
          if (!parsed.descriptor) {
            return;
          }
          let templateEncoded = parsed.descriptor.template
              ? parsed.descriptor.template.content
                  .replace(/[\n\r]/gi, " ")
                  .replace(/\"/gi, '\\"')
                  .replace(/\s\s+/gi, " ")
              : null,
            templateLine = templateEncoded ? `\ntemplate: "${templateEncoded}",\n` : "",
            justScript = parsed.descriptor.script.content,
            startPos = justScript.indexOf(COMPONENT_START),
            scriptAndTemplate =
              justScript.substring(0, startPos + COMPONENT_START.length) +
              templateLine +
              justScript.substring(startPos + COMPONENT_START.length);
          fs.writeFile(
            filePath.replace("vue", "ts"),
            scriptAndTemplate,
            (err) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(`The file ${filePath} has been created!`);
            }
          );
        } catch (parseError) {
          console.log(parseError);
        }
      }
    });
  } catch (readError) {
    console.log(readError);
  }
}

glob("**/*.vue", {}, (err, files) => {
  console.log(`Convert ${files.length} SFCs...`);
  files.forEach((filePath) => {
    convertSFC(filePath);
  });
});
```