# Compiling *.vue file to *.js file for using in cdn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-sfc, vue3-sfc-loader

Are there any methods to compile some `Component.vue` files to some javascript file? So that compiled js can be included in HTML and used with vue CDN.

For example, Lets' say we have some component `Component.vue`, given below

```
<template>
    <div class="demo">{{ msg }}</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            msg: "Jatin Garg",
        };
    },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.demo {
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Now we want to include the compiled Component.js in below HTML file.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="/path/to/Component.js"></script>
        <script src="vue@next"></script>
        <body>
            <div id="app">
                <component></component>
            </div>
        </body>
        <script>
            const app = Vue.createApp({});
            app.component("component", Component);
            app.mount("#app");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

I know a library called `vue3-sfc-loader` that does a similar thing. But rather using ".js" file it directly takes the `Component.vue` file and compiles it.
Basically, I want to compile the `.vue` file offline

Comment: This is what Vue CLI does exactly.

Comment: I used `vue build Component.vue lib`. But it didn't work and produced Very Huge file.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you need to convert your file, not compile it. So you can to find a script that could do this, or create it by yourself.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47790188/12414998) the answer to the similar question with a suitable script.

Comment: Yeah that would work without style, but I was not able to do it with style.

Comment: As far as I know, there are no tools or libs that support css yet and no one is developing in this direction, so you can make it happen :)

Comment: If somehow we can add `data-v-xxxxx`  to style and template. Then We can use above approach to include scoped style. I read that `vue-loader` does the same using PostCSS. But I have no idea  how to use `vue-loader` to generate this as output.

Comment: That `data` attribute is given by the Vue, so in the build process Vue knows which component need to be stylised and `vue-cli` (or another loader) uses the value of that attribute to assign styles